# Tips for this integral?

Tags: integration

I need to find $$\int \frac{x^4+3}{(x+1)^2(x^2+1)}~dx$$

but unsure of how to do it. Any hints evaluating this particular integral please?

Comment: Perhaps you could foil the denominator and then use long division to simplify the integrand a bit. And then use partial fractions to split any remaining fractions up if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Partial fractions. Determine $A,B,C,D,E$ such that
$$
\frac{x^4+3}{(x+1)^2(x^2+1)}=
A+\frac{B}{x+1}+\frac{C}{(x+1)^2}+\frac{Dx+E}{x^2+1}
$$
Then your integral is elementary.

Comment: Ok will do that now. Is there an easy way to determine how to split a general integral into partial fractions, I always forget what they should be like and consequentially can't do the integral. Thanks.

Comment: @RobertRichardson Yes, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

As the degree of the numerator & denominator are same write the integral as $$1+\frac A{x+1}+\frac B{(x+1)^2}+\frac{Cx+D}{x^2+1}$$

$1$ as the coefficients of the highest degree terms are same

Comment: Ok will do that now. Is there an easy way to determine how to split a general integral into partial fractions, I always forget what they should be like and consequentially can't do the integral. Thanks.